# cygwin cmake cannot find boost library

Tags: c++, boost, cmake, cygwin

I am trying to configure Cmake from the Cygwin terminal of windows, my Boost library is located at /usr/src/boost_1_54_0/libs. My CMake configuration file contains:

```
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS ON) 
set(Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED ON) 
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME OFF) 
find_package(Boost 1.54.0 COMPONENTS date_time filesystem program_options serialization thread REQUIRED) 
include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
```

However, CMake gives me the following error:

```
Boost version: 1.54.0

Boost include path: /usr/src/boost_1_54_0

The following Boost libraries could not be found:

        boost_date_time
        boost_filesystem
        boost_program_options
        boost_serialization
        boost_thread

No Boost libraries were found.  You may need to set BOOST_LIBRARYDIR to the
directory containing Boost libraries or BOOST_ROOT to the location of
Boost.
```

Then I tried to manually specify the directory of the Boostlib with the following line before the *find_package* method:

```
set(BOOST_LIBRARYDIR /usr/src/boost_1_54_0/libs)
```

But it doesn't work, either.

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: The message indicates that CMake can find the headers, but not the libs. What's the contents of `/usr/src/boost_1_54_0/libs`? What happens if you use `Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS OFF`, because that's what I am using successfully on Cygwin?

Comment: Have you built the few not header-only libraries of boost like http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html suggests?

Comment: The directory /usr/src/boost_1_54_0/libs includes all those packages. If I set the parameter OFF I got the same error.

Comment: @JackJianpengCheng: If it would contain the correct libraries, there would likely be no error. That's why we're asking... Boost can build shared and static libraries, in a variety of folder structures. If your setup does not match what CMake FindBoost.cmake expects, you turn up dry. But we cannot tell you what went wrong without *seeing* your setup... You might also want to check out the various "related" links to the right. Lots of existing questions about "cmake does not find boost"...

Comment: In fact, I simply follow the setup here:http://www.boerngen-schmidt.de/2013/07/installing-boost-1-54-0-c-libraries-in-cygwin/

Comment: @JackJianpengCheng: As an aside, are you aware that [libboost is part of the Cygwin distribution](https://cygwin.com/cgi-bin2/package-grep.cgi?grep=libboost-devel&arch=x86) and can be installed using Cygwin's setup.exe?

Comment: Still waiting for (an excerpt of) `ls -l /usr/src/boost_1_54_0/libs/`, or a word on how you fared with the Cygwin package...

Answer (score 0):

To find Boost libraries, cmake relies on the environment variable `BOOST_ROOT`. It should point to the directory containing your Boost `lib` (and not `libs`) and `include`

Define it in Cygwin before calling cmake and it should work.

In csh:

```
setenv BOOST_ROOT "/usr/src/boost_1_54_0"
```